# Issue getting identifier from XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I have some code similar to Jason Lattimer's below that used to work however now fails.  I can find the "Identifier" in the wsdl anymore.  Can anyone provide assistance on this?

```
function GetADFS($url) {
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "XrmServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

    $response = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    $responsedom = new DomDocument ();
    $responsedom->loadXML ( $response );

    // **************************************************       
    // **************************************************
    // Can no longer find this Identifier
    // **************************************************
    // **************************************************
    $identifiers = $responsedom->getElementsbyTagName ( "Identifier" );
    $identifier = $identifiers->item ( 0 )->textContent;

    return str_replace ( "http://", "https://", $identifier );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in namespace 'ms-xrm' so replace

```
$identifiers = $responsedom->getElementsbyTagName ( "Identifier" );
```

with

```
$identifiers = $responsedom->getElementsbyTagNameNS ( "ms-xrm","Identifier" );
```

and check. Next thing is to check in actual WSDL if you see this node if not then there may be a problem with configuration of your CRM because that node is only available when you are using ADFS.

Comment: Thanks!! You answered my question.  I'm using AD but not ADFS.  How do I get something similar for an internal AD deployment?

Comment: What do you mean by 'something similar'? Without ADFS there is no 'Identifier' node.

Comment: So how do I find the Active Directory server if its not a federated setup?

Comment: There is neither AD nor ADFS (with the exception when your CRM is configured for ADFS) address in WSDL.